# P5.js cursor reveal base image beneath top image only within the cursor radius

Tags: p5.js

example of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that uses p5.js
to reveal an image beneath another image when the cursor hovers over it

P5.js cursor reveal base image beneath top image only within the cursor radius

[link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/ianecross/pen/ZEMMjza)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>p5.js Image Reveal on Hover</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <img class="base-image" src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20220620/ourmid/pngtree-white-cloud-weather-climate-png-image_5215887.png">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS style.css**

```css
.container {
position: relative;
}

.base-image {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

canvas {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

**JS sketch.js**

```js
let canvas;
let baseImage;
let revealImage;
let revealRadius = 50;

function preload() {
   baseImage = loadImage('https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20220620/ourmid/pngtree-white-cloud-weather-climate-png-image_5215887.png');

   revealImage = loadImage('https://png.pngtree.com/png-vector/20220620/ourmid/pngtree-cloud-weather-climate-free-cutout-nature-png-image_5215871.png');
}

function setup() {
   canvas = createCanvas(500, 500);
   canvas.parent('canvas');
}

function draw() {
   background(255);
   image(baseImage, 0, 0, width, height);
   if (mouseIsPressed) {
      reveal();
   }
}

function reveal() {
   noStroke();
   fill(0);
   ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, revealRadius, revealRadius);
   loadPixels();
   for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
         let d = dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY);
         if (d <= revealRadius / 2) {
            let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
            pixels[index] = red(revealImage.get(x, y));
            pixels[index + 1] = green(revealImage.get(x, y));
            pixels[index + 2] = blue(revealImage.get(x, y));
            pixels[index + 3] = 255;
         }
      }
   }
   updatePixels();
}
```

cannot understand why its not working.

Comment: Could you format your post, please? This is difficult to read and understand. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. Yeah I know it is !!! But this system wouldn't allow ny to post unless I indented it 4 spaces. I didn't understand, couldn't post,  but it seemed to work when I bullet pointed everything for some strange reason???

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but if you look at many other posts from new users, they're well-formatted, so it can be done. Please [edit] and try again. Thanks.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is use p5.js to show a div beneath a div within the radius of the cursor. Like flashlight

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clip function to clip() and stop the drawing context. Also, your images in the fiddle are having a cors issue look at the inspect window.

```
function reveal() {
  drawingContext.save();
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, clipSize, clipSize);
  drawingContext.clip();
  copy(revealImage,
       mouseX-halfClip, mouseY-halfClip, clipSize, clipSize,
       mouseX-halfClip, mouseY-halfClip, clipSize, clipSize);
  drawingContext.restore();
}
```

where revealImage is the revealed image.

EDIT or like how you were doing you have to change the images to avoid cors also you can't access the canvas and give it a parent in the setup function you can make an await if it is needed.

```
function awaitCanvas(){
  canvas=select('canvas');
  if(!canvas){
  requestAnimationFrame(awaitCanvas);
  }else{
    canvas.parent('canvas');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<script>
  function sketch(p) {

    let canvas;
    let baseImage;
    let revealImage;
    let clipSize = 50;
    let halfClip = 25;
    p.preload = () => {
      baseImage = p.loadImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXAxUucEZQBa-rVi28Hh6HCMEZ7-1JMnZOpLn5u9lBoQ&s');
      revealImage = p.loadImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSRCm5KNqq_84W1zvrAFNytFdlfte-l2mg7vO--bmh6Vw&s');
    };

    p.setup = () => {
      canvas = p.createCanvas(500, 500);

    };
    var resized = false;
    p.draw = () => {
      if (!resized) {
        revealImage.resize(p.width, p.height);
      }
      p.background(255);
      p.image(baseImage, 0, 0, p.width, p.height);
      if (p.mouseIsPressed) {
        reveal(p);
      }
    }

    function reveal(p) {
    p.drawingContext.save();
      p.ellipse(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, clipSize, clipSize);
      p.drawingContext.clip();
      p.copy(revealImage,
           p.mouseX-halfClip, p.mouseY-halfClip, clipSize, clipSize,
           p.mouseX-halfClip, p.mouseY-halfClip, clipSize, clipSize);
      p.drawingContext.restore();
      }
  }
  new p5(sketch);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Solomon, thats what im looking for. Only problem is that it  staggers too much its not smooth the more i increase the canvas size. Also, I nee it to be full dimensions of the current screen, so I tried:    canvas = p.createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight); which usually works, but not in this case. Plus i need it on mouse hover. So I tried  p.mouseOver(reveal(p)); But it did not work. Can you advise on these issues. Many thanks again for your solution :)

Comment: I edited to use the first reveal function look now it will be much more smooth and faster. use p.windowHeight and p. windowWidth when using the instantiated p5. with the new p5 thingy

Comment: Thanks so much! You have really helped me. I needed it on mouseMove(). But figured that out myself. Best wishes :)

Comment: how can i set the base and reveal to divs instead of images? thanks

Comment: hi, instead of revealing an image underneath another, can the images be replaced with div elements with text inside them instead? I'm trying to achieve an effect like the following: https://loconoco.webflow.io/

Comment: Hi that looks like a div with a filter invert color in CSS following the  mouse and border radious set to 50% all orders and fades out when the mouse is outof the area. I don't think you want p5 but I am sure you could. With the second text drawn underneath in a canvas and clipped to the size with no pointer events and stuff.

Comment: look here https://webdevpuneet.com/hero-with-cool-spotlight-effect-and-cursor-tracking/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, brilliant! Thankyou very much for taking the time to help me with this, much appreciated Solomon 